# Spring'14 (bug?) with apex:repeat and sets

Tags: apex, visualforce, bug, spring14

I think I may have found a bug with iterating over a set in spring'14.

So I have some code that creates a set (using set so it will be unique) and then on the page it iterates over the set using an `apex:repeat`. The problem is that it wont save. If I change the **set** to a **list** it saves and works fine. I know (or am pretty sure) I have been able to use sets in the past with `apex:repeat` but now I cannot. Here is the code (simplified) and the errors:

```
public class CreateOrders {

  public Set<Item__c> selectedItems {get; set;}

  public CreateOrders() {
    selectedItems = new Set<Item__c>();
    for (Item__c i : findItems()) {
      selectedItems.add(i);
    }
  }
}
```

then on the page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!selectedItems}" var="itm">
  <apex:outputfield value="{!itm.Name}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

and the resulting error is: **Save error: Could not resolve the entity from apex:outputField value binding '{!itm.Name}'.  apex:outputField can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.**

and when I try removing the `apex:outputfield` by using `apex:outputtext` or nothing like so:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!selectedItems}" var="itm">
  <apex:outputtext value="{!itm.Name}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

OR

```
<apex:repeat value="{!selectedItems}" var="itm">
  {!itm.Name}
</apex:repeat>
```

I get this error: **Save error: Unknown property 'SetValue.Name'**

and its the same with any field/object. But when I switch the **Set** over to a **List** it works without any issues...

**UPDATE**

So on a hunch I checked the version, and it was on 28. When I upgraded it to 29, it allowed me to save with `apex:outputfield` **only**, but on refresh of the page I still got the same errors:

**Could not resolve the entity from apex:outputField value binding '{!itm.Name}'. apex:outputField can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.**

and it still wouldnt let me save if I changed the `apex:outputfield` to `apex:outputtext` or used no apex tags it would still not save and give me the error:

**Save error: Unknown property 'SetValue.Name'**

On versions older than 29 (20-28 that I have tested) they all error like 28, 29 is the only one with a *slightly* different behavior.

When saving with just `{!itm}` it allows the save to happen, and the page just shows the Id of the Item.

Comment: Did you try to save with a set property + vf repeater as older api versions ?

Comment: see updated question, but both version 28 and 29 wont work with sets/apex:repeat

Comment: How about displaying just {!itm}, this also caused problems?

Comment: no, that allows the save to happen, and on the page, it shows the item Id.. but this only works if i dont use apex:outputfield, apex:outputtext works and using no tags works

Comment: Though I can see using a list and using list.addall(set) as workaround, I confirm the same behavior with my developer account too. Lists are working fine, but sets are not with apex:repeat tag

Comment: I don't think this is a Spring '14 bug. My developer org is on Winter and I can't use Sets in a repeat element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a new behaviour in Spring 14.

In the discussion forums - [Table rows repeating for each Child Record present in Parent to Child Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008zJ4IAI) there is a comment from [@bob-buzzard](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/416/bob-buzzard) in 2011:

> It seems to be a problem when the set contains sobjects - I've just checked back on mine and they've been primitives.  It smacks that the "SetValue" in the page (sounds low-level possibly a java class) can convert to a string for display if its a primitive, but not when a complex object.

There is an example of using a primitive `Set` with an apex:repeat in the answer [Peter Knolle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/154/peter-knolle) provided to [another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/541/102).

---

As an alternative to using a `Set` you could instead use a `Map` (assuming your records have been inserted and have an Id). Then use the syntax from [Referencing Apex Maps and Lists](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm) to drive the repeat over the maps keys and lookup the corresponding value.

Controller:

```
public class CreateOrders {
    public Map<Id, Item__c> selectedItems {get; set;}

    public CreateOrders() {
        selectedItems = new Map<Id, Item__c>();
        for (Item__c i : findItems()) {
            selectedItems.put(i.Id, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!selectedItems}" var="itm">
    <apex:outputfield value="{!selectedItems[itm].Name}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: yeah I ended up using maps instead :-P but I still feel sets should work with sobjects..

Comment: From Ideas : [Allow Visual Force apex:repeat to work with Maps](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IIn5AAG) it appears things weren't always so great with Maps either. You will probably need to go down the ideas path to get it resolved for Sets :/

Answer (score 3):

I will try to confirm this but I think tis is caused because set is non-ordered collection of data and you just can't get element number [i] and ask it for values like repeat block try to do - and thats why it work with list

For now lets be patient and wait for one of MVP to speak :)

Comment: You can use a Set as the value in a repeat. See [Apex Repeat Using Set Collection](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/541/102). It might be a special Case for sObjects.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008zJ4IAI) is a 2011 comment from MVP @bob-buzzard: "It seems to be a problem when the set contains sobjects - I've just checked back on mine and they've been primitives.  It smacks that the "SetValue" in the page (sounds low-level possibly a java class) can convert to a string for display if its a primitive, but not when a complex object."

Comment: Thats kinda what I suspected... Thanks for finding this! :)